# Handling same external API calls during concurrent requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, race-condition

I have two controllers which have

```
before_action :get_user
```

and a private method in both of those controllers

```
def get_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.create_profile if @user.profile.nil?
end
```

The `create_profile` method makes an API call to the third-party service to create the profile. When two concurrent requests hit these two controllers from the same user, it makes duplicate API calls(two) when the profile is nil in the database. How can I make sure that I don't make a single request instead of two here?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the the API requests should be idempotent, so doing it twice will not create two profiles but e.g. just return the profile if it already exists.

However, if this API is not under your control and you need to make sure the request is only done once there are several ways to do this.

One way could be to use a database lock by find_or_create the record before you do the request, lock it and flag it as externally created after the response.

Something like

```rb
class User
  def create_profile
    profile = profile.first_or_create
    return if profile.external_created_at

    profile.lock do
      return if profile.external_created_at

      api_response
      profile.update_attributes!(external_created_at: Time.now)
    end
  end
end
```

Otherwise you can e.g. use a distributed lock with Redis.

https://github.com/leandromoreira/redlock-rb
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html